# copying data to another workbook and adding to last row used

Tags: vba, excel

I have the following code which I got to work, copying a range from one workbook to another, however in need help so that when I open a different workbook I can copy the same range to the last row used in the consolidation file.

```
Sub ValuePaste()

    Workbooks("04.17.17 SHELBY.xlsx").Worksheets("Summary $500-$10K").Range("B8:F21").Copy  
    Workbooks("Consolidated_template_new1_WA.xlsx").Worksheets("test").Range("C4").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
End Sub
```

Comment: Does "different workbook" have a name or just a new workbook? You only have .xlsx extensions, where is this code running from, are you pasting this code to editor each time you want to run it? You do most of the job manually so far, please be more specific in your question.

Comment: the process is a go to a excel file in the cloud and open it on a daily basis.  the file has a different name base on date. so in the sample code that would be "04.17.17 Shelby" for that day, then following day it will change to "04.18.17 Shelby" etc.  So I'm tying to get a code that I can copied from one active workbook range to my destination (consolidated file) range.  I have a separate file where I the macro will be running from.

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub ValuePaste()
Dim loLastRow As Long

Workbooks("04.17.17 SHELBY.xlsx").Worksheets("Summary $500-$10K").Range("B8:F21").Copy

With Workbooks("Consolidated_template_new1_WA.xlsx").Worksheets("test")
   loLastRow = .Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row + 1
   .Range("C" & loLastRow).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
End With

End Sub
```

The variable loLastRow will contain the last Row of the worksheet specified in the "with" command above. After that the Range object uses this Information to build the first empty cell after the last used one.

Comment: Hi Pearli, thank you for your help, one question. is there a way to modified the code so that it will select from an active workbook to the consolidated one?  the code above will work only with the 04.17.17 workbook however, if want to copy the same range for the following day then it will not work. Could we replace "Workbooks("04.17.17 Shelby.xlsx") with "This Workbook.Worksheets("Summary $500-$10K").Range ("B8:F21").Copy"  or something like that?

Comment: Yes, sure. You can use any referrence you want to. But, if you use "ThisWorkbook" you have to be sure, that the activated Workbook is the one, you want to use. Another Option is, if the names of the workbooks have the same structure, that you ask for that date through an inputbox or something and save that in another variable.